# Don't understand how to copy data from CTkLabel

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

How to copy info from custom tkinter label?

I've made password manager and want to select text from label and copy it but can't. I used pyperclip but this is not what i need. Directly want to select text and copy it!

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
import pyperclip

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x300")

def copy():
    pyperclip.copy(lbl1.text)
    lbl2.configure(text="Successfully")


lbl1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(text="Website")
lbl1.pack()

lbl2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(text="")
lbl2.pack()

btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(text="Copy", command=copy)
btn1.pack()


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: label's doesn't meant to be drag your mouse a bit and select things. You can bind a click event and then copy via pyperclip. However, if you wanna drag and select kind of things, you should use Text widget

Comment: Sadly can't make it with "Text" because I want to make it looks cool with CTk

Comment: Both Label and Text aren't the appropriate widget. An Entry widget would be the easiest solution. It looks like customtkinter has an Entry widget.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to specify the parent window by `master`. Then you can do it by `.cget` attribute.

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")

def copy():
    copied_var = lbl1.cget("text")
    lbl2.configure(text="Successfully")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x300")


lbl1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Website")
lbl1.pack()

lbl2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="")
lbl2.pack()

btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Copy", command=copy)
btn1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

You must scrutinize this page: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki

Answer (score 0):

im also making a password manager!
The way i copied the text of a label to the clipboard when clicking it, is the next:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

text_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Your_Text", cursor="hand2")
text_label.pack()
text_label.bind("<Button-1>;", self.on_click)

def on_click(self):
    text = text_label.cget("text")
    self.clipboard_clear()
    self.clipboard_append(text)
```

Hope you found this useful.